# Calculating non-prime divisors from primes

Tags: python, math, factorization

Having a number e.g. `510510`

The prime divisors are: `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]`

Using the list of primes, what could an efficient way to calculate the non-prime divisors be?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the list of prime factors contains all factors according to there multiplicity, you can use

```
prime_factors = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
non_prime_factors = [reduce(operator.mul, f)
                     for k in range(2, len(prime_factors) + 1)
                     for f in itertools.combinations(prime_factors, k)]
```

to get all the non-prime factors.  Note that you might get duplicates if some prime factors have a greater multiplicity than one -- these can be filtered out using `set(non_prime_factors)`.

(NumPy wouldn't help too much in this context.)

Edit: By "contains all factors according to there multiplicity" above I mean that (say) 2 should appear twice in the list if it is a prime factor of multiplicity 2, i.e. 4 is the highest power of 2 which is a factor of the number.

Edit 2: If there are prime factors with a high multiplicity, the above code is inefficient.  So just in case you need this, here is efficient code for this case also.

```
primes = [2, 3, 5]
multiplicities = [3, 4, 5]
exponents = itertools.product(*(range(n + 1) for n in multiplicities))
factors = (itertools.izip(primes, e) for e in exponents if sum(e) >= 2)
non_prime_factors = [reduce(operator.mul, (p ** e for p, e in f))
                     for f in factors]
```

Comment: You've forgotten about powers

Comment: @Elfalfer: No, I did not.  Please read the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: Regardless, this has the same problem that CashCow's algorithm has; given 2 * 2 * 3 * 5, 2 * 3 * 5 gets calculated twice. set() filters duplicates but it's not the most efficient answer.

Comment: @senderle: I usually write simple code that works, and only optimise if it is needed.  There is no indication that the OP needs high multiplicities -- in fact her example has all multiplicities equal to 1.  Just in case, I added an efficient version for the high-mulitplicity case in the spirit of my first solution.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Sorry, didn't mean to offend. I was probably overemphasizing the "efficient" part of the question.

Comment: @senderle: No offence taken :) Just explaining what I did and why.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something get you started. In this method factors is a map of primes to their occurance in your number. So, for your case it would look like `[2 : 1, 3 : 1, 5 : 1, 7 : 1, 11 : 1, 13 : 1, 17 : 1]`. Note this finds *all* divisors but the modification should be trivial.

```
def findAllD(factors):
    pCount = [0 for p in factors.keys()]
    pVals  = [p for p in factors.keys()]
    iters  = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [c+1 for c in factors.values()])
    ret    = []

    for i in xrange(0, iters):
        num = 1
        for j in range(0, len(pCount)):
            num *= pVals[j]**pCount[j]

        ret.append(num)

        for j in range(0, len(pCount)):
            pCount[j] = pCount[j] + 1

            if pCount[j] > factors[pVals[j]]:
                pCount[j] = 0
            else:
                break;

    return ret
```

Comment: +1, nice -- this is faster than mine; or as fast as mine if I multiply out the factors instead of using lists and then `reduce`.

Comment: @senderle: thanks, this was in my library for Project Euler so I tried to be as efficient as possible without making it too cryptic to extend later.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number **510510** equals **2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17**, every pair of those primes multiplied are also non-prime divisors:

```
>>> divmod(510510, 2*3)
(85085, 0)
>>> divmod(510510, 11*17)
(2730, 0)
```

6 (=2*3) and 187 (=11*17) are non primes, and are propper divisors to 510510.

You can easily find all the pairs of numbers using itertools:

```
>>> a=[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 2))
[(2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 7), (2, 11), (2, 13), (2, 17), (3, 5), (3, 7), (3, 11), (3,
 13), (3, 17), (5, 7), (5, 11), (5, 13), (5, 17), (7, 11), (7, 13), (7, 17), (11
, 13), (11, 17), (13, 17)]
```

All you need to do then is to multiply the first number of the pair to the second one:

```
>>> a
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
>>> b=list(itertools.combinations(a, 2))
>>> [d*e for d,e in b]
[6, 10, 14, 22, 26, 34, 15, 21, 33, 39, 51, 35, 55, 65, 85, 77, 91, 119, 143, 187, 221]
```

Finally, you need to repeat the same procedure to triples, four-touples, etc. passing the appropiate number as the secondth parameter to combinations():

```
>>> b=[reduce((lambda o, p: o*p), y, 1) for x in xrange(2, len(a)) for y in itertools.combinations(a, x)]
>>> b
[6, 10, 14, 22, 26, 34, 15, 21, 33, 39, 51, 35, 55, 65, 85, 77, 91, 119, 143, 187, 221, 30, 42, 66, 78, 102, 70, 110, 130, 170, 154, 182, 238, 286, 374, 442, 105, 165, 195, 255, 231, 273, 357, 429, 561, 663, 385, 455, 595, 715, 935, 1105, 1001, 1309, 1547, 2431, 210, 330, 390, 510, 462, 546, 714, 858, 1122, 1326, 770, 910, 1190, 1430, 1870, 2210, 2002, 2618, 3094, 4862, 1155, 1365, 1785, 2145, 2805, 3315, 3003, 3927, 4641, 7293, 5005, 6545, 7735, 12155, 17017, 2310, 2730, 3570, 4290, 5610, 6630, 6006, 7854, 9282, 14586, 10010, 13090, 15470, 24310, 34034, 15015, 19635, 23205, 36465, 51051, 85085, 30030, 39270, 46410, 72930, 102102, 170170, 255255]
```

Comment: This is only a subset of the non-prime divisors.

Answer (score 0):

If D is the set of prime divisors of N and `d = |D|` than `N = \prod_i=1^d(D[i]^p[i])` for some `p[i]` (where p[i] is a natural number > 0).

From this point of view you can use a bit mask to go through all possible combinations of elements from `D` and generate partial products, which will divide `N`. And of course go through all powers `1...p[i]` for each element.

In this case you'll get all possible non-prime divisors of N.

Comment: Maybe you meant `N = \prod...` instead of a sum?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to generate ALL the divisors of 510510:

Each prime divisor appears just once in the product.

Each prime divisor could be used or not used. So think of it as a binary set from 0 to 127 and look at the bits. Iterate through the numbers and if the bit relating to the prime divisor is set, include that prime.

eg binary 1011010 means use numbers 17, 11, 7 and 3 so multiply these to get 3927

Of course 0000000 relates to 1 and 1111111 to 510510, so you might not want to count "1 and itself".

If you have a number that has multiple factors you have to count 0 to n on that factor, eg 60 is 2 * 2 * 3 * 5 so 0-2 uses of 2, 0-1 use of 3, 0-1 use of 5, total of 12 possible factors (including 1 and 60).

Comment: There's a problem with this though; in the case of 2 * 2 * 3 * 4, 1011 and 0111 map to the same divisor. This isn't a big deal for smaller numbers (just use set() on the results to filter duplicates) but if your prime factorization includes 2 ** 32, this will be slow.